# How can I solve this datetime error using dataframe.to_sql command?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I trying to create a sql table, based on a pandas dataframe, but it returns the error below:

```
'22007', '[22007] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. (242) (SQLExecDirectW); [22007] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)', Tipo: <class 'pyodbc.DataError'>
```

Curiously, the error raises in some machines, so I suspect that is driver configuration.

```
df['dtref']=dtref.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df['dtref']=pd.to_datetime(dtref,format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Obs: dtref variable is a datetime from python.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: check your data

Comment: I suspect that is a driver problem, because It runs perfectly in some machines

Comment: Please show the `to_sql` line and sample data. And carefully think of any common traits of machines that code fails. Without knowing fuller background of your entire process we cannot know but I don't think it is driver but data. Is data updated differently by machines? Data frame may carry an incorrect date (e.g., `February 29, 2019`, `September 31, 2020`